# Quoting a password at the end of a sentence: Where to put the point?

Tags: punctuation, tech-writing

Recent Slashdot [article](http://politics.slashdot.org/story/15/08/17/1544241/virginia-ditches-americas-worst-voting-machines):

> They feature Wi-Fi that can't be turned off (protected, however, with a WEP password of "abcde"), an unencrypted database, and administrative access with a hardcoded password of "admin."

Is the password `admin` or `admin.`?

Here it might be easy to guess, but in technical documentation for enterprise software it would be hugely ambiguous and could cause a lot of trouble if understood wrongly. Especially if the password is `4@$p).<..`.

Is there a convention for punctuation around passwords in English documentation?

Comment: No conventions, but this is one case in US written English where it would make sense to put the period outside the quotation marks.

Comment: It's easy with what's rather misleadingly called the 'British punctuation style'. The full stop would go outside the quote if it wasn't part of the quote. And personally, I'd double-punctuate for clarity ( ... with a hardcoded password of "admin.".) This is general English, nothing to do with passwords (which would be off-topic). //  (I can find references recommending double punctuation for clarity, and the use of the indicative in place of the 'subjunctive.)

Comment: For absolute clarity you could change the structure of the sentence so that the password is not at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My password is "admin". 
The Quotation mark makes it understandable.

Comment: Hello, Olawale. But what if the period is an included character in the six-character-long password? A 'password' doesn't have to be (and is usually considered better not being) part of the English lexicon. eg 45FFfF*;0@8.h (So this password is not a word!)

Comment: If the password contains "odd" characters, I'd write it on a separate line.

Comment: I do not understand what you find confusing but in that case (odd characters), it could be my password is "pa$.5gf_'=". End of quote means the end of the password.

Comment: Writing the password on a new line like the other person suggested would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could blockquote it as

> admin

or preformat as

`admin`

> The password is `admin`

You can also use a colon to get rid of the sentence structure.

> The password is: `admin`